# graphics problem and no volume control icon after installation

Tags: installation, video, graphics, display, volume-control

After my installation, I saw a message saying 22 files were broken. Then a window appeared, and I selected the broken files and removed them.  Since then, I haven't had a volume control icon on my laptop (acer extensa5630), and there's a thick black line on the right side of my window .  How can I fix these problems? Please help.

Comment: I don't have answer for you just yet, but in the future, don't remove broken packages immediately. Consider trying to reinstall them instead.

Comment: see that you have indicator-sound installed because volume icon is the part of indicator applet

Answer (score 1):

First open a terminal.
Then write :

For your package problem :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

(you'll have to write your password)

And for the sound problem :

```
gnome-volume-controler-applet &
```

Comment: Could you please add some additional details to your answer. It's very vague and in it's given state difficult to decipher.

Comment: ok for correcting your package problems, open an terminal and write the fallowing line : "sudo dpkg --configure -a" then push enter. It will ask you your password, write it. For the voume manager probleme, in your terminal, write : "gnome-volume-controler-applet " and press enter